# Lucene QueryParser in multiple threads: synchronize or construct new each time?

Tags: java, lucene, thread-safety, query-parser

I have a web application where users submit queries to a Lucene index.  The queries 
are parsed by a Lucene
[`QueryParser`](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_3/api/contrib-surround/org/apache/lucene/queryParser/surround/parser/QueryParser.html).  I learned the hard way that `QueryParser` is not thread-safe.

Is it better to use a single `QueryParser` instance, and synchronize on calls to its `parse()` method?  Or is it better to construct a new instance for each query?  (Or would I be better served by a pool of `QueryParser`s?)

I know that in general questions like this depend on the particulars and require profiling, but maybe someone out there can say definitively "`QueryParser`s are extremely inexpensive/expensive to construct"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a new one each time. These are lightweight objects and the JVM handles object creation and garbage collection very well. Definitely do not use an  object pool.

Comment: +1 yes, definitely no reason to pool (or share a single) `QueryParser` object. Further reading: [Java theory and practice: Urban performance legends, revisited](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp09275/index.html)

Comment: Thanks!  @WhiteFang34, that link is about the low cost of allocation in general, but it's surely worth pointing that there **are** some types of objects where construction is not cheap because a lot of work is done beyond the allocation itself.  In the Lucene world one is often reminded to share a single `IndexSearcher` for performance reasons.