# Lucene.Net Parallel Search

Tags: c#, multithreading, lucene.net

I am creating a Lucene.Net based search engine application in C# with a single index. As a requirement, I need to optimize runtime for a test run with multiple (5) queries. Therefore, I wanted to use a separate thread for each search, returning results similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314155/returning-a-value-from-thread) post. My code looks like this:

```
// load information needs
List<InformationNeed> informationNeeds = FileReader.readInformationNeeds(collectionPath);             

// each search has its own thread referenced in this list
List<Thread> threadList = new List<Thread>();

// each search has its own result referenced in this list
List<SearchResult> searchResults = new List<SearchResult>();


foreach (InformationNeed informationNeed in informationNeeds){

    // create searchOptions
    SearchOptions searchOptions = new SearchOptions(DEBUG_pre_processQuery, informationNeed.getInput());

    // run search
    SearchResult result = null; // Used to store the return value
    var thread = new Thread(
       () =>
       {
       result = startSearch(searchOptions);
       Console.WriteLine("end search for IN nr " + informationNeed.getID() + "results = " + result);

       //add results to list
       searchResults.Add(result);

       });
    thread.Start();
    threadList.Add(thread);
}

// block main thread until all threads finished
foreach (Thread t in threadList){
    t.Join();
}

return searchResults;
```

However, I am getting a Lucene.Net.QueryParser.ParseException [see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dytD2.png) that I do NOT get when running the searches sequentially.

Please comment if I let something unclear. I would appreciate any help on this issue.

Comment: You're not synchronizing access to `searchResults`. That's going to cause issues.

Answer (score 2):

You need to synchronize access to `searchResults` or multiple threads will modify it at the same time. Or you can use the async pattern and return a `Task<SearchResult>` from your async method and not use the same `List` for every thread.

Also, declaring `SearchResult result` outside of the thread is just asking for trouble in the same way that `searchResults` is causing trouble. Declare it inside the thread.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. In the `startSearch` method I have a call to `QueryParser` which is not threadsafe as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525018/lucene-queryparser-in-multiple-threads-synchronize-or-construct-new-each-time). Resolved this by adding a `lock` to the `QueryParser` instance.

Comment: Yes I also put a `lock` there. Thank you!